# Is it mere slang to use the verb 'stick' in place of 'versus', as in 'Us three 'stick' you four'?

Tags: slang, dialects

When I was a child (well over a half-century ago) in Norfolk, we would, when playing football talk of 'Team A *stick* Team B. When arranging sides informally we would say 'Us three *stick* the rest of you, meaning the three of us will play against the rest of you.

I had always assumed this was Norfolk slang dialect, peculiar to both place and time. But tonight I heard my Mancunian grandson using it with some other kids with whom he was playing football.

It does not appear as a meaning of the verb *stick* in the OED. So one assumes it is simply urban slang.

Does anyone else know anything about it? What further information does anyone have on the matter?

Comment: Very interesting. I’ve never heard this at all before. Is _stick_ being used as a verb or as a preposition here; i.e., would you say, “Yesterday, it was Team A stick Team B” or, “Yesterday, Team A stuck Team B”?

Comment: In USA, I've never heard it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I supposed either of those would be possible. But it seems like a verb to me. Though *stuck* might rarely be used I feel sure I have heard it. The most frequent occurrence is when kids are informally deciding on teams.

Comment: The expression 'X stick Y' was quite common in 1950s Oldham, but only in a register I'd label slang. There was a verby rather than a prepositiony feel to it, but I don't remember it ever being inflected: as you say, it was 'Us three stick the rest of you' _and_ 'John stick [not sticks] Billy'.

Comment: Could it derive from orthgraphy: "*Today, in Citi Stadium it's Yankees **/**  Mets*"?

Comment: I'm from South Wales and we used it as children in the 80s.

Comment: @DanBron What an interesting though! Except that in the UK where 'stick' seems to be uniquely used, we never write Arsenal/Chelsea always Arsenal v Chelsea.

Comment: @PugFugly From the comments it would appear UK wide. At least we have examp;les from Norfolk, Manchester, Oldham and South Wales!

Comment: I'd put quotation marks around the words, the asterisks are too distracting IMO. It is weird that EL&U editor doesn't allow italics in question titles, I wonder why that is?

Comment: I guess you didn't mean Norfolk, Virgina, or one of the 4 lesser known Norfolks in the US.

Comment: This is the best I could find that refers to ["stick" and "a little boy"](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/09/15/article-2756228-2161E24000000578-909_636x502.jpg)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Re asterisks. Yes good point. I have edited.

Comment: @Barmar I refer to Norfolk, England, a county with a dialect of its own and where the English language is often conjugated in a most interesting way.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If it were a case of Cameron stick Salmond, the former wouldn't stand a chance in Scotland. But thankfully the 'Yes' inclined have a far wider array of personalities 'sticking' them.

Comment: WS2 a case of Politics sticking English slang ? :)

Answer (score 2):

This was used commonly in Northampton (England) when I was a boy in the '60s/'70s. I've just been having a conversation about it with friends in a group of Cobblers (Northampton Town FC) supporters, and they all remember it. I agree that it was often used with an element of challenge in it, as in "Me, John and Bill stick", meaning we'll take on the rest of you.

Answer (score 1):

In my youth in Southern Ontario (1960's) this expression was used in the context of "pick-up" sports - typically posed as a proposal or challenge regarding the make-up of the teams.  It wasn't specific to football.

Comment: That is exactly how it is used in Britain. You 'pick-up' teams and then one team  'sticks' the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I've never heard that expression before. I imagine 'stick' is being used as a short version of the expression "stick it to the man" or "stick it to 'em". There is a short reference to this on the urban dictionary. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=stick%20it%20to%20the%20man I'd say, WS2, that your Norfolk expression is perhaps more colloquial rather than slang.

Comment: I somehow doubt it has any connection with that. From what others report it seems unique to the UK, though widely used outside Norfolk. 'Stick it to 'em' sounds American  to me. It was certainly not an expression I would have been aware of in the 1950s when we were saying 'Us three stick you four'.