# What does "amletic" mean?

Tags: meaning

Today I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25848589/1698557) on StackOverflow and saw the word *amletic*, which I've never come across before (as a native speaker).

> ...and I have an amletic doubt about one thing.

I looked it up and it [doesn't appear](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amletic?s=t) in any dictionary that I can find.  However, it does have a respectable number of [hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=amletic), all with a similar usage as in the original question (in doubt, question, or otherwise asking advice):

- [Amletic problem](http://teadl.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/amletic-problem/)
- [Amletic question!](http://www.head-fi.org/t/433616/amletic-question)
- [Amletic question](http://forums.pcper.com/showthread.php?292469-Amletic-question)
- [Amletic doubt](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/854062/filter-account-type/staff)
- [Which Distortion?? (Amletic dillemma from Italy)](http://www.harmonycentral.com/forum/forum/guitar/acapella-29/1717099-)

Is this just some bizarre case of a [perfectly cromulent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent) word that somehow grew out of nothing?

Comment: Several of the sites you linked to, and various others returned in Google's SERPs, appear to be written by native Italian speakers.  According to Wiktionary, in Italian, "*amletico*" means "***ambiguous***", and in general, the questions all appear to be along the lines of "*I'm torn; I'm on the fence; I don't know which to choose.*". The word doesn't appear in Google Books or nGrams (except as a bad OCR rendering of "*athletic*"). Bottom line: I take this to be a sort of false-friend coinage for "ambiguous".

Comment: @DanBron - you should post that. Good job.

Comment: Hamletic is a legitimate term and carries more or less the same meaning http://books.google.it/books?id=m_BUlVZjxKEC&pg=PA247&dq=Hamletic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HwwXVP-xMcavO6jHgMAD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Hamletic&f=false and here's another example written by the Italian intellectual, Massimo Cacciari. But I'm not sure if someone else translated his words. http://books.google.it/books?id=zQCQYFpLLXwC&pg=PT44&dq=Hamletic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OwwXVMa7Fs2wPNKsgdAD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Hamletic&f=false

Comment: @Mari-LouA Annoying though that "Hamletic" is mostly undefined in English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than an English word

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even though it's being used in English prose--with anglicized spelling--as a loan word?

Comment: [Concerning the adjective of “Hamlet,” no standard print or online dictionary listed one ... The “Hamletic” form occurred in a few articles by Western native speakers of English, but **not enough to justify it as standard**.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3LqkTGcW1ooC&pg=RA1-PA183&dq=%22hamletic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=whMXVKKqKcTQ7AaxioGgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hamletic%22&f=false)

Comment: @PatrickQuirk It seems to be an Italian-derived form, used only by Italians. I'd call that a mistake, rather than a loan word.

Comment: And who knows, @FumbleFingers the saying might well catch on, it is after all based on one of *Shakespeare's* most famous characters. It's hardly of Indian origin! Why not class it as dialectal? The first link I provided is from a book written by  By Kenneth Burke.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I haven't really looked into this one, but it appears to be an Italian word (without the **H**) rather than an English one. I could just about stand a question on *"Is there an acceptable adjectival form of **Hamlet**?"*, but not when the starting point is a foreign word anyway.

Comment: What _is_ the corresponding English word? I don't recognize 'Hamletic'. Is it 'like Hamlet'? Or is all we got is 'indecisive'?

Comment: Hmm @FumbleFingers so you haven't really looked into it. Well in Italian it is written *Amletico*, obviously Italian speakers believe that it is an English expression, they leave out the -o and turn an Italian adjective into English. They're not far off. :) On a side note the a word beginning with the letter -h is very rare  in Italian unless it is a loaned word, e.g. Hotel, Hamburger, but Italians will pronounce them as "oTEL" and "amBURger" .

Comment: @@Mari-Lou: Being Italian, you're better equipped than most to answer OP's question. I didn't *downvote*, because I accept it might not be obvious to OP what's going on here. But I closevoted *because it's not about English* as I understand it. Apart from the Off Topic answer *This is an Italian term referencing Hamlet* (or more specifically, *Hamlet's existentialist doubts*), all I can see here is *To what extent is this particular foreign word acceptable in English?* - which seems OT POB to me (as would be the same for ***Hamletic***).

Comment: The OED has never heard of it.

Comment: @WS2 The OED has never heard of [*stick*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196400/is-it-mere-slang-to-use-the-verb-stick-in-place-of-versus-as-in-us-three) meaning "against" or "versus" when used by schoolboys in Norfolk and Manchester. Does that mean it's not a valid expression? :) P.S I am trying to find anything, something on that usage but no luck so far.

Comment: I observe that the construction "I have a doubt about X" [meaning "I have a *question* about X"] is already into variant-English territory; I've never heard native speakers of Am or BrEng say that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But if 'amletic' is what is being claimed it is the sort of word one might expect to find in the OED. 'Stick' in the sense I raised is clearly street slang.

Comment: @WS2 what exactly is being claimed of *amletic*? I believe it is a loan expression, its correct English equivalent would be *Hamletic*. Evidently, there are fluent speakers of English who believe it to be English. The term is easily understandable. It serves a purpose, a function: it expresses a concept which is missing in the language.   And where is it written that the OED *has to* contain every "English-sounding" expression uttered by speakers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it is a wrong translation of Hamletic.

[Amletico](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/amletico/):

> - Di Amleto, proprio di Amleto, personaggio dell’omonima tragedia di Shakespeare, con riferimento al suo carattere irresoluto e pieno di contrasti.
> - (Hamlet (- Of Hamlet), the character of Shakespeare's tragedy, with reference to his character irresolute and full of contrasts.)

Source: www.treccani.it

As a side note; it is curious how the adjectival use  of Hamlet is used more in Italy than in the English speaking world.

[Ngram - Hamletic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hamletic%2C%20hamletic%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHamletic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chamletic%3B%2Cc0)

[Ngram - amletico](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amletico&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camletico%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: That doesn't fit in the context of any of the questions the OP linked to.  Though I do agree it's a bad translation from Italian.  See my comment.

Comment: @DanBron - in Italian 'amletico' does not mean ambiguous, but irresolute, dubious. See the Treccani link above.

Comment: see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amletico#Italian

Comment: @DanBron - yes..it is wrong.. Treccani is like OED for English language. Please don't trust the translation you posted.

Comment: @DanBron it is often used to mean when you are undecided (torn) between two or more options. Referring to Hamlet's continual  indecisiveness. The Treccani is a very trustworthy and serious source.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, hey, I'm not going to argue with someone whose profession is to help Italians learn English :) +1 on Josh's answer from me.